# LeftIsDown not toggling

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm a newbie trying to throw together a small test program in which I have an EVT_LEFT_DOWN event bound to a StaticBitmap like so:

```
wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN(imageBitmap, image_click_handler)
```

image_click handler looks something like this:

```
image_click_handler(self):
    self.Skip()
    while self.LeftIsDown():
       Do something
```

Basically, I'm trying to implement dragging when I click on the image. However, the self.LeftIsDown() method never returns false, which causes an infinite loop.

I feel like I'm doing something really silly.  I've been following the documentation here (http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.MouseEvent-class.html), which is for an older version of WxPython (I'm using 3.0.0.0).  Perhaps that is an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wxPython is an event driven environment.  Your event handler gets called when someone presses the left mouse button, and until the event handler finishes no other events will get through to your program.  Your program has no means of becoming aware of the release of the button since all new events are stuck in a queue waiting for your handler to return.  In general in event handlers it is dangerous to use anything resembling an infinite loop.

The solution is typically in several parts: (1) set up a timer to send periodic events but don't start it yet.  (2) In your init_click_handler you start this timer and return.  (3) Write a timer event handler where you "Do something" once per event.  (4) When you get a EVT_LEFT_UP you stop the timer (another event handler), or alternatively you can check LeftIsDown() within the timer event handler and stop the timer when it's False.

Comment: Hmm...maybe I should elaborate on what "Do something" actually is. Essentially, I have an image and I want to "paint" over it, except, instead of painting over it, I want to, say, sum the red values of the pixels I painted. Do you think there's a better way to do it that doesn't involve timers?  I can see how to implement it based on what you're saying (button down event toggles a flag, then have a mouse_move event accumulate values as long as the flag is set, then when mouse goes up, turn flag off).  That seems kinda messy though

Comment: Also, now that I think about it, your explanation doesn't make sense to me.  LeftIsDown() seems to be a method that reads a state and not an event.  I appreciate the help though :)

Comment: So I followed your tips, Paul, and it works well.  Thanks!  Still hoping someone has a better way of doing this...using the explicit keyword global in my solution feels really weird.

Comment: From the wx documentation for the function LeftIsDown(): 

"wxMouseEvent::LeftIsDown
bool LeftIsDown() const

Returns true if the left mouse button is currently down, independent of the current event type.

Please notice that it is not the same as LeftDown which returns true if the event was generated by the left mouse button being pressed. Rather, it simply describes the state of the left mouse button at the time when the event was generated (so while it will be true for a left click event, it can also be true for a right click if it happened while the left mouse button was pressed)."

Comment: In the scheme I outlined the timer events are only emitted between the LEFT_DOWN event and the LEFT_UP event, so I don't understand why you need a variable (let alone a global) to tell you that.  And adding Timers is no big deal; it's virtually impossible to write a useful event-driven program without them.